# Installed postman but content is difficult to read

Tags: postman

I installed postman under Kubuntu 18 and have difficulties working 
with it as too small fonts and very pale colors:
[image]
hardly can see the content of the postman ...
If there is a way to tune it?

Thanks!

Comment: It has zoom under the view menu to make the font bigger and a dark theme under the settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **set** font size in '**Setting**'

The '**Setting**' option will be in the **top right corner**

**PFA** for detail

[image: small font to big font]

Answer (score 2):

Use shortcut `Clt + '+'` for windows and Linux and `Cmd + '+'` for mac